# Error 404 page showing instead of wordpress admin panel ( Website Hosted on AWS EC2 instance, Ubuntu)

Tags: wordpress, apache, amazon-ec2, http-status-code-404, custom-error-pages

I am developing a wordpress site but after connecting EC2 instance's Ip to the domain, I can't access the wordpress admin panel. It shows 404 error.

I do research about it, but nothing works. I put .htaccess file code for some reference.

```
# Only allow direct access to specific Web-available files.

# Apache 2.2

\<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c\>
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
\</IfModule\>

# Apache 2.4

\<IfModule mod_authz_core.c\>
Require all denied
\</IfModule\>

# Akismet CSS and JS

\<FilesMatch "^(form.js|akismet.js|akismet-frontend.js|akismet.css)$"\>
\<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c\>
Allow from all
\</IfModule\>

    <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
        Require all granted
    </IfModule>

\</FilesMatch\>

# Akismet images

\<FilesMatch "^logo-(a|full)-2x.png$"\>
\<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c\>
Allow from all
\</IfModule\>

    <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
        Require all granted
    </IfModule>

\</FilesMatch\>
```

[Page Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wndoj.png)

Site Link:  https://theglobalcybersecurityandinformationtechnology.com/

Technologies I used in this website are below.

- Running on Ubuntu,
- Webserver Apache and
- Database MySql.

If anything I missed or you think not sufficient data please, comment it. I'll give it asap.

I try to fixed it from many sources but it not work. I want to fixed the page problem and get back wp-admin panel.

( P.S. I am a beginner in terms of deployment )

Comment: Hi, I think your question is off-topic for this site. Read the docs [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Thanks for you response. I will also try this question on another stack exchange but from the docs I get this point-> 
    Operating and managing your own website, including questions about SEO, domain names, and web/email hosting, ask on Webmasters

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution for this problem. I have to terminate the instance and reinstall everything from the start. And before connecting my domain name to the website I set permalink to wordpress setting>>General.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ou95l.jpg)